# Check if events are true and enabling a button based on the results

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I have the following code:

```
    timeLeftFinished = false;
    boolean agreed = jCheckBox1.isSelected();
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            timeLeftFinished = true;
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(0, taskPerformer);
    timer.setInitialDelay(5000);
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
    while (timeLeftFinished == true && agreed == true) {
        jButton3.setEnabled(true);
```

I would like jButton3 to be enabled if both `timeLeftFinished` and `agreed` are true how do i go about checking if both are true and only enabling jButton3 when Both are true ?

Side note:I'm using netbeans Gui Builder perhaps the IDE could generate the code to bind the events?

Is creating another `ActionListener` to check if both are true at every second a feasible implementation ?

Comment: I'de recommend putting a getter/setter on the bools and add some logic to the getters/setters that will enable/disable jButton3 if both are not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check and monitor the distinct states of both the check box and the timer...

```
jCheckBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       agreed = jCheckBox1.isSelected();
       updateState();
   }
});
//...
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        timeLeftFinished = true;
        updateState();
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(0, taskPerformer);
//...

protected void updateState() {
    jButton3.setEnabled(timeLeftFinished && agreed);
}
```

Remember, you are operating in an event driven environment, it is very rare that anything will occur in a linear fashion

Also, remember, the UI operates within a single thread of it's own.  All interactions and modifications to the UI state are expected to occur within the context of this the thread.  If you do anything that stops this thread from running (like using long running loops for example), the Event Dispatching Thread won't be able to process new events (including repaint request), which means your loop is likely to never exit and your program will appear to have hung, because, basically it has...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Nah, once you've agreed, you're mine >:)

Comment: LOL. I'm crazy but not mad.